# Reformatting a string from a text file into set of strings python

Tags: python, string, reformatting

I have a line which is read from a text file as follows:

```
line="('18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1')"
```

I'd like to convert this into a set of strings as such:

```
expected=['18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1']
```

Any ideas? I tried re.sub() to at least get rid of the brackets, to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
line="('18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1')"
new_line = list(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

Output:

```
['18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1']
```

Or, using `re.findall`:

```
import re
vals = re.findall('\d+\-\d+', line)
```

Output:

```
['18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1']
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval` method to implement the require. as following:

```
line = "('18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1')"
result = list(eval(line))
expected = ['18-1', '29-1', '30-1', '42-1', '44-1']

assert expected == result
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is sufficient for this task. There's no need to use the dangerous `eval` function.

Comment: yes, `ast.literal_eval`is more safe. I agree with you.